# Understanding 〜に入る

Tags: words

> ウェストコットの言うことは純然たる事実であった。個の力で勝るはずのエレンが目標を仕留め損なっているのは、毎回精霊たちが**妨害に入っ**てくるからに他ならない。(Date
> a live, novel)

I have looked up the word 入る in many dictionaries but can’t find a relevant definition for 妨害に入る in this context. So what does 〜に入る mean here? Or how should I understand it generally (when it is used in an abstract sense)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps to understand that this に in 妨害に[入る]{はいる} is

> **に**
> (Ⅲ)動作・作用の結果、状態や目的などを表す。
> ...
> ㋗《下に移動を表す動詞を伴い、動詞連用形や動作性名詞に付いて》移動の目的を表す。
> 「映画を見**に**行く」
> 「家まで忘れ物を取り**に**帰る」
> 「町に買い物**に**出る」

<sub>(source: 明鏡国語辞典)</sub>

In other words it indicates the purpose of a movement verb like [入る]{はいる}, 行く, 帰る, etc. So 妨害に[入る]{はいる} means to enter/step in/approach in order to interfere/get in the way.

A few other examples:

> 見舞いに行く
> To go in order to visit someone [who is sick]
>
> 学生が質問に来る
> A student comes in order [to ask] a question

Answer (score 1):

> So what does 〜に入る mean here?

〜に入る here is just a modification for 妨害, so it is basically equivalent to 妨害してくる.

> Or how should I understand it generally

You can think of X に入る as "come and do X" or "start to do X".

Here are examples that I came up with:

- 仲裁に入る
- 成層圏に入る

Comment: I think 成層圏に入る means you physically enter the sphere, right?